# shifting in C and assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips, bit

Consider the following C code that writes and reads to and from memory mapped I/O.

```
volatile int* switches = (volatile int*) 0x1b430010; 
volatile int* leds = (volatile int*) 0xabbb8050; 
int temp = ((*switches) >> 6) & 0x3; 
*leds = (*leds & 0xff9f) | XXX;
```

From the C code above it is possible to derive that some bits are read from the 16-bit switch port and used to turn on or off some LEDs, without affecting the other LEDs on the 16-bit LED port. One missing expression is marked as XXX. Write out what expression XXX should be, so that the LEDs are correctly turned on or off.

The answer is XXX = `temp << 5`. 
When i try to translate to assembly and calculate in bits, I got temp is 0 after `((*switches) >> 6) & 0x3;`, so why `temp << 5` is valid here because shifting 0 does not make any different? (maybe I misscalculated, can provide all my calculations in bits if neccessary)

Comment: This code will not work since `int` is signed and you get implementation-defined behavior when right-shifting. If this boils down to arithmetic shift on the given MCU, the MSB is set, then followed by a left shift, you invoke undefined behavior bugs. Answer: the original code is too badly written to be used, it needs to swap `int` for `uint32_t`. Unlike in assembler, shifts don't have well-defined behavior for signed variables in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xff9f` is `1111111110011111` in binary. The mask zeroes bit 5 and 6, keeps the others.

`temp` is a value on 2 bits because the code and-masks with `0x3`, `11` in binary (all other bits are zeroed). You have to shift it left 5 times to be able to insert in the final value by `|` masking.

(The fact that you're getting 0 for `temp` is either a bug or expected depending on the input data, it doesn't change the answer above)

Comment: wait, why `temp` is a value on 2 bits? I got `0000 0000 0110 1101 0000 1100 0000 0000` after `((*switches) >> 6)`, `0x3` is `11`, so the value after `and` operation is `0` which is temp, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: see my edit. masking with `& 0x3` keeps only the lowliest bits

Comment: @nihulus : You aren't suppose to be shifting `0x1b430010` right by 6. The switches are read via MMIO An integer is read from address `0x1b430010`. That is what `(*switches)` does